# Facing issue using activemq with PostgresDB

Tags: java, jboss, jms, activemq-classic

I am getting the below exception while publishing messages to the activmq. I am using JBOSS with ActiveMQ which is using PostgresDB.

I have configured the below **activemq.xml** file in  directory.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">



    <bean id="postgres-ds" class="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource" destroy-method="close">    
    <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>    
    <property name="databaseName" value="activemq"/>    
    <property name="portNumber" value="5432"/>    
    <property name="user" value="postgres"/>    
    <property name="password" value="admin123"/>    
    <property name="dataSourceName" value="postgres"/>    
    <property name="initialConnections" value="1"/>    
    <property name="maxConnections" value="10"/>  
</bean>
```

And in broaker tag

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
<persistenceAdapter>            
        <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="activemq-data" dataSource="#postgres-ds" lockKeepAlivePeriod="5000">         
            <adapter>               
                <postgresql-jdbc-adapter/>          
            </adapter>              
            <locker>                    
                <lease-database-locker lockAcquireSleepInterval="10000"/>               
            </locker>           
        </jdbcPersistenceAdapter>        
    </persistenceAdapter>
```

Below has been configured standalone-full.xml file in JBOSS.

```
<resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="activemq-ra.rar">
                <archive>
                    activemq-ra.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="ServerUrl">
                    tcp://localhost:61616
                </config-property>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="jms/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ActiveMQConnectionFactoryPool" use-ccm="true">
                        <xa-pool>
                            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                        </xa-pool>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
                <admin-objects>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="queue/IP_NAME" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ActiveMQQueue.IP_NAME">
                        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                            IP_NAME
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="queue/IP_NAME_2" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ActiveMQQueue.IP_NAME_2">
                        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                            IP_NAME_2
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                </admin-objects>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
```

Exception:

> 17:31:28,466 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) ARJUNA016041: prepare on < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0a4b02b4:34361599:5a7aea01:26, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a4b02b4:34361599:5a7aea01:28, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:/jms/ConnectionFactory > (XAResourceWrapperImpl@1c956d35[xaResource=org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnection$1@5daa43e4 pad=false overrideRmValue=null productName=ActiveMQ productVersion=5.9.1 jndiName=java:/jms/ConnectionFactory]) failed with exception XAException.XAER_RMFAIL: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
>       at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.toXAException(TransactionContext.java:793)
>       at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.prepare(TransactionContext.java:487)
>       at org.apache.activemq.ra.LocalAndXATransaction.prepare(LocalAndXATransaction.java:126)
>       at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.prepare(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:177)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelPrepare(XAResourceRecord.java:213)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doPrepare(BasicAction.java:2530)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doPrepare(BasicAction.java:2497)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.prepare(BasicAction.java:2074)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.End(BasicAction.java:1485)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:98)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1189)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:284) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:367) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:245) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at com.deb.ec.courier.api.MessageBus$$$view4.publish(Unknown Source) [courier-core-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267) [weld-core-1.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137) [weld-core-1.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263) [weld-core-1.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:115) [weld-core-1.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56) [weld-core-1.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105) [weld-core-1.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
>       at com.deb.ec.courier.jms.MessageBus$-1689182988$Proxy$_$$*Weld$Proxy$.publish(MessageBus$-1689182988$Proxy$*$$_Weld$Proxy$.java) [courier-jms-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.deb.ec.courier.impl.CourierMessageBusSingleton.publish(CourierMessageBusSingleton.java:117) [courier-core-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.deb.ec.courier.impl.CourierPublishContract.publish(CourierPublishContract.java:26) [courier-core-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.deb.ec.courier.reference.ECRecordServlet.doPost(ECRecordServlet.java:72) [classes:]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at com.deb.service.provider.server.web.SpfServletFilter.doFilter(SpfServletFilter.java:68) [service-provider-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
>   Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
>       at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54)
>       at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1408)
>       at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.syncSendPacketWithInterruptionHandling(TransactionContext.java:757)
>       at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.prepare(TransactionContext.java:453)
>       ... 71 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
>       at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.adapter.DefaultJDBCAdapter.doAddMessage(DefaultJDBCAdapter.java:242)
>       at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCMessageStore.addMessage(JDBCMessageStore.java:158)
>       at org.apache.activemq.store.memory.MemoryTransactionStore$3.run(MemoryTransactionStore.java:342)
>       at org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JdbcMemoryTransactionStore.prepare(JdbcMemoryTransactionStore.java:75)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transaction.XATransaction.prepare(XATransaction.java:188)
>       at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransactionBroker.prepareTransaction(TransactionBroker.java:247)
>       at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.prepareTransaction(BrokerFilter.java:129)
>       at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processPrepareTransaction(TransportConnection.java:510)
>       at org.apache.activemq.command.TransactionInfo.visit(TransactionInfo.java:98)
>       at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:330)
>       at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:194)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:125)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:301)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)
>       at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
>
> 17:31:28,478 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) ARJUNA012073: BasicAction.End() - prepare phase of action-id 0:ffff0a4b02b4:34361599:5a7aea01:26 failed.
>   17:31:28,478 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) ARJUNA012075: Action Aborting
>   17:31:28,716 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component TransactionalJmsMessageBus for method public abstract void com.deb.ec.courier.api.MessageBus.publish(java.lang.String,com.deb.ec.courier.api.CourierMessage) throws com.deb.ec.courier.error.CourierException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:138) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:118) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:284) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:367) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:245) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]

Comment: Note, I did add the `<bean>` to your original "code"/xml in your question during an edit (you may not see it yet) as it was missing.  It isnt really missing is it?

Comment: Also, you're getting this error `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter` is the jdbc driver being deployed with your app or does it exist in the lib folder of the server?

Comment: Hi JGlass,Thanks for response. Modified the tags properly.I am using postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar for postgres driver.

Comment: Hi JGlass,The above issue got resolve It was because of jdk9. In jdk9 DatatypeConverter.java file is not present. Have used jdk9 for ActiveMQ and jdk1.8 in Jboss, thats why issue.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above issue got resolve It was because of jdk9. In jdk9 DatatypeConverter.java file is not present. Have used jdk9 for ActiveMQ and jdk1.8 in Jboss, thats why issue.Now i changed jdk9 to jdk1.8 and above issue got resolved. Thanks

Comment: Glad to see you got it working!  I'm surprised JBoss even ran under JDK9?  Might I suggest you accept your own answer, e.g. click the grey checkbox - that way it doesnt show as unanswered!

Comment: No JGlass, JBoss is running under java1.8.Thanks